# text/graphical editor with dynamic alignment/margins/paddings

Tags: text-editor, image-editor, editor

I'm looking for an editor that is able to auto-adjust the positions of neighboor elements based on their content size and alignment/margins/paddings.

I'm used to web development where the browser will dynamically (re)render a webpage based on specified CSS properties and content size so I'm looking for a similar behaviour for editing text/graphical documents.

If I have two elements next to each other and I change the width of the first one, I want the editor to move the second one so that the space between the elements stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the [CudaText](https://cudatext.github.io/) editor, which supports Python plugins. You can write a plugin which handles on_change event, and do the needed indentations, ie insert blank lines or tab-chars.

Usual editors don't do such indents.